# read bits, write bits data to arbitrary position in char array in c++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I created functions to read bit data from arbitrary bit position of char array to long long int, and I also created function to write data to char array from vector bool. 
However, I do not really like my implementation since I think it has burden implementations in order to read and write bits. 
Can anyone see my implementation and enlighten me for better implementation?

Here is my implementation to write bit data from `vector<bool> bitdataForModification`

`unsigned char*& str` is original char array 
`int startBitLocation` is arbitrary bit position to read from 
`int sizeToModify` is the size in bits for modification

```
void setBitDataToBitPosition(unsigned char*& str, int startBitLocation, int sizeToModify, std::vector<bool>& bitdataForModification){
    int endBitLocation = startBitLocation + sizeToModify-1;
    int sizeChar = (endBitLocation - startBitLocation)/8;

    //Save leftover data    
    int startCharPosition = startBitLocation/8;
    int startLeftOverBits = startBitLocation%8;

    //endPosition
    int endCharPosition = endBitLocation/8;
    int endLeftOverBits = 7-(endBitLocation%8);

    unsigned char tempChar = str[startCharPosition];
    unsigned char tempLastChar = str[endCharPosition]; // store last char

    int posBitdata = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < startLeftOverBits; i++){
        str[startCharPosition] <<= 1;
        str[startCharPosition] = (str[startCharPosition] | ((tempChar >> (7-i)) & 0x1));
    }

    for(int i = startCharPosition*8 + startLeftOverBits ; i <= endBitLocation ; i++){
        str[i/8] <<= 1;
        if(posBitdata <= endBitLocation){
            str[i/8] = (str[i/8] | ((bitdataForModification[posBitdata]) & 0x1));
            posBitdata++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < endLeftOverBits ; i++){
        str[endCharPosition] <<= 1;
        str[endCharPosition] = (str[endCharPosition] | ((tempChar >> i) & 0x1));
    }

}
```

I do not like above function because it copies from original char[] to temp char[] and copy back the bits I need.

Following is my read function I implemented.
It reads from char array and copy the data to `long long int data`

```
void getBitDataFromBitPosition(unsigned char* str, int startBitLocation, int sizeToRead, unsigned long long* data){
    int endBitLocation = startBitLocation + sizeToRead;
    int sizeChar = (endBitLocation - startBitLocation)/8;

    int startCharPosition = startBitLocation/8;
    int endCharPosition = endBitLocation/8 +1;

    vector<bool> bitData;

    int bitCnt = 0;
    for(int i = startCharPosition; i < endCharPosition; i++){
        unsigned char tempChar = str[i];

        for(int j = 7 ; j >= 0 ; j--){
            int curLoc = ((i*8)+(bitCnt%8));
            if(curLoc >= startBitLocation){
                if(curLoc < endBitLocation){

                    bool temp = ((str[i] >> j) & 0x1);
                    bitData.push_back(temp);
                }
            }
            bitCnt++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = bitData.size() -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--){
        *data <<= 1;
        *data = (*data | bitData[bitData.size()-i-1]);      
    }
}
```

I think it is burden to copy to bool vector and copy back to long long int.
Can anyone provide better solution for me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want a review of your code, and suggestions on how to improve it, [there's a site for that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh I didn't know the site. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the code is c++, not c, so please remove the 'c' tag

Comment: @user3629249 removed Thanks!